# Form validation file input with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to accomplish a multiupload of some files and it requires that all of them will be uploaded in the form. I'm using jQuery Validation.This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" 
      layout:decorator="layout">
<head>
    <title>Documentos</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myform").validate({
                rules: {  
                    file:{
                        required: true,
                        extension: "pdf"  
                    }  
                },
                messages: {
                     file:{
                       required: "Please select the document!",
                       accept: "You can only upload PDF files."
                    } ,
                }       
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="header">
        <h1>
            <span>Empleado</span>
            <i><b th:text="${employee.name}"></b></i>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div layout:fragment="content">
           <div class="box box-default">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">
                        <span>Perfil</span>
                        <i><b th:text="${employee.profile.name}"></b></i>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <form id="myform" th:action="@{'/employee/' + ${employee.id} + '/save/documents'}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <table id="files-list" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

                            <tr th:each="documento : ${documentsList}">
                                <td th:text="${document}"/>
                                <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Documents</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
           </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Every single time it accepts empty fields in the inputs. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it works fine to me...

[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8c7cysuf/)

You have mixed content in your `<head>` - this could be the issue. All CDNs should be either http or https i.e:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's true! Thank you. But the validation only works for the first row, if the rest of them are empty it accepts the submit action. I don't know if I have to generate the rows of the files dynamically with js and if so, the number of files depends of the size of the documentsList and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do in the script.

Comment: Oh - well there is only one file upload input in your code example - maybe you can give more sample from your code so we can better see what you're trying to do.